# How to ensure that my code use the whole capacity of the GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am training a ResNet-50 network on a large database. When checking the percentage of use of my GPU, I found it varying just between 0% and 4%! although I am using tensorflow-GPU.
Here is my CPU and GPU rate of use:
[image]

When I run these two command lines:

```
 from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
 print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get

```
 [name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
  }
 incarnation: 4622338339054789933
 , name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 13594420839
 locality {
 bus_id: 1
 links {
 }
 }
 incarnation: 17927686236275886371
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Quadro 
 P5000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute 
 capability: 6.1"
 ]
```

and when I run 
     nvidia-smi
I get
[image]

Could anyone help me with an easy explanation how to correctly and totally exploit my GPU? 
I have to mention that I am using ImageDataGenerator object during my training with its two methods flow_from_directory and fit_generator, so could I set specific parameters such as workers parameter to enhance my GPU rate of use.
Here is how I am using ImageDataGenerator

```
  input_imgen = ImageDataGenerator()
  train_it = input_imgen.flow_from_directory(directory=data_path_l,target_size= 
  (224,224),
                                      color_mode="rgb",
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      class_mode="categorical",
                                      shuffle=False,
                                      )

  valid_it = input_imgen.flow_from_directory(directory=test_data_path_l,target_size= 
  (224,224),
                                      color_mode="rgb",
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      class_mode="categorical",
                                      shuffle=False,
                                      )

  model = resnet.ResnetBuilder.build_resnet_50((img_channels, img_rows, 
  img_cols), num_classes)
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

  filepath=".\conv2D_models\weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}- 
  {val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"

  mc = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, save_weights_only=False, verbose=1, 
  monitor='loss', mode='min')

  history=model.fit_generator(train_it,
                    steps_per_epoch= train_images // batch_size,
                    validation_data = valid_it, 
                    validation_steps = val_images// batch_size,
                    epochs = epochs,callbacks=[mc],
                    shuffle=False)
```

Comment: The most likely reason is that the model is too small and does not really need GPU training. Only large models require lots of compute and profit from using a GPU.

Comment: Possible reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887816/why-tensorflow-gpu-is-still-using-cpu

Comment: do you think that a ResNet-50  with 3D convolution layers trained on a large database (20K images) with a batch size=32 does not require a GPU?

Comment: How do you use `ImageDataGenerator`?

Comment: @Sharky please take a look to my question edit.

Comment: Do you have any preprocessing inside ImageDataGenerator ?

Comment: What batch size are you using?

Comment: @Sharky no, I didn't use any type of preprocessing inside the generator

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I used 32 as batch size

Comment: Seems like your processes data faster than you generate it. Have you considered using `tf.data` API?

Comment: @Sharky no I have no idea about this API, how could this one help me here please?

Comment: Please take a look https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Comment: @Sharky Thank you, I will read this.

Comment: Increase the batch size, that should increase utilization, try something like 256

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro The problem is that when increasing the batch size to more than 32, with (224,224) target size, I got a memory error. although I have 32G RAM.

Comment: Your hard drive utilization is sitting at a very high percentage, this is probably the culprit. Work to cache your data in memory, no GPU or `tf.data` pipeline can save you if you simply can't get the images off your disk fast enough.

Comment: @YoloSwaggins I think this is due to the training process as the capture of the source utilization is taken during the training. If I check that when no training is performed on the machine, I found that the hard drive utilization is just 32%.