# Trouble installing Keras GPU in R - invalid version specification

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I've followed a number of guides to try and install Keras with a GPU on my new laptop. Some details:

- Windows 10 64bit
- Nvidia T1000 GPU
- R version 4.0.4
- I've followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements) for software dependencies, including CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1.1. Based on the cuDNN site, this is the correct cuDNN for CUDA 11.2. I've also updated the drivers.
- I've copied the cuDNN files from bin, include, and lib to their respective folders in NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit.
- I've also added those folders and the cuDNN folder to my PATH environment variables.

Here are the files in my CUDA bin folder (I've tried installing CUDA 10, 10.1, and 11.2):

```
list.files("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.2\\bin\\")
 [1] "bin2c.exe"                "compute-sanitizer.bat"    "crt"                      "cu++filt.exe"            
 [5] "cublas64_10.dll"          "cublas64_100.dll"         "cublas64_11.dll"          "cublasLt64_10.dll"       
 [9] "cublasLt64_11.dll"        "cuda-memcheck.exe"        "cudafe++.exe"             "cudart32_110.dll"        
[13] "cudart64_100.dll"         "cudart64_101.dll"         "cudart64_110.dll"         "cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll" 
[17] "cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll"  "cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll"  "cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll"  "cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll" 
[21] "cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll"  "cudnn64_8.dll"            "cufft64_10.dll"           "cufftw64_10.dll"         
[25] "cuinj64_112.dll"          "cuobjdump.exe"            "curand64_10.dll"          "cusolver64_10.dll"       
[29] "cusolverMg64_11.dll"      "cusparse64_10.dll"        "cusparse64_11.dll"        "fatbinary.exe"           
[33] "nppc64_11.dll"            "nppial64_11.dll"          "nppicc64_11.dll"          "nppidei64_11.dll"        
[37] "nppif64_11.dll"           "nppig64_11.dll"           "nppim64_11.dll"           "nppist64_11.dll"         
[41] "nppisu64_11.dll"          "nppitc64_11.dll"          "npps64_11.dll"            "nvblas64_11.dll"         
[45] "nvcc.exe"                 "nvcc.profile"             "nvdisasm.exe"             "nvjpeg64_11.dll"         
[49] "nvlink.exe"               "nvprof.exe"               "nvprune.exe"              "nvrtc-builtins64_112.dll"
[53] "nvrtc-prev"               "nvrtc64_112_0.dll"        "nvvp.bat"                 "ptxas.exe"
```

I've tried guides [here](https://medium.com/@abasauri92/a-hopefully-useful-guide-to-installing-gpu-version-of-keras-in-r-c6cdbf6928ba), [here](https://narenakurati.com/keras_r_cuda_install/), and [here](https://mpopov.com/blog/2017/06/11/r-win-gpu-tensorflow/).

I've successfully run:

```
tensorflow::install_tensorflow(gpu = TRUE)
reticulate::use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")
tf$constant("hello")
```

I then get the messages:

```
2021-03-08 20:54:50.917771: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:00.607511: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:02.286421: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro T1000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-03-08 20:55:02.286702: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:02.657731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:03.052477: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:03.230033: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:03.526342: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:03.920362: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:03.930081: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.440275: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-08 20:55:04.440969: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-03-08 20:55:04.450175: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x211965ca050 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-08 20:55:04.450424: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-03-08 20:55:04.450851: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro T1000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-03-08 20:55:04.451300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.451552: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.451803: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.451982: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.452149: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.452363: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.452502: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-03-08 20:55:04.452708: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-08 20:55:05.372995: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-08 20:55:05.373218: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2021-03-08 20:55:05.373358: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2021-03-08 20:55:05.373600: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2917 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro T1000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021-03-08 20:55:05.376339: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x211965dcad0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-08 20:55:05.376629: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Quadro T1000, Compute Capability 7.5
tf.Tensor(b'hello', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

However, if I then try

```
keras::install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")
```

in a new RStudio session, I get

```
Error: invalid version specification
```

But I then tried running `conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu` from the command line and that installed OK. If I run a test with Keras using the IMDB dataset, it seems like it's working OK nevertheless:

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(10000)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

returns:

```
2021-03-08 21:51:14.726620: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.456659: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro T1000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-03-08 21:51:16.456844: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.460816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.465207: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.466657: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.470899: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.473512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.482108: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.482375: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-08 21:51:16.484124: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-03-08 21:51:16.495226: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1edbf69c2d0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-08 21:51:16.495403: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-03-08 21:51:16.495774: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro T1000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496029: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496131: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496247: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496347: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496438: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496703: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-03-08 21:51:16.496866: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-08 21:51:17.007480: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-08 21:51:17.007586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2021-03-08 21:51:17.007676: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2021-03-08 21:51:17.007896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2917 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro T1000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021-03-08 21:51:17.011318: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1edbf6afdd0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-08 21:51:17.011464: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Quadro T1000, Compute Capability 7.5
```

Any help is much appreciated :upside_down_face:

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. However, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904153/is-r-keras-using-gpu-based-on-this-output) and the fact that the final code chunk above includes `Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0` I thought it was possible that GPU install worked even though the `keras::install_keras()` didn't?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is within the latest R keras package. I downgrade the keras package by using

```
require(devtools)
install_version("keras", version = "2.3.0.0")
```

and then keras could be installed properly